# Kivy: how to implement recursive dropdown button?

Tags: kivy

I did some research but I can't create a recursive dropdown button. I would like to have 1 DropDown that contains 2 child-DropDowns that contain 2 buttons, like this: ***DropDown(DropDown(Button, Button), DropDown(Button, Button))***. Here is my code, it does not work (***TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen_manager'***)

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    button_text = StringProperty('Show possibilities')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown1 = CustomDropDown1(self)
        self.dropdown2 = CustomDropDown2(self)

    def open_drop_down(self, widget):
        self.dropdown1.open(widget)

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class CustomDropDown1(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager

    def on_select(self, data):
        self.sm.button_text = data

class CustomDropDown2(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager

    def on_select(self, data):
        self.sm.button_text = data



Builder.load_file("debug.kv")

class MyAppli(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

.kv:

```
<MyScreenManager>:

    MyScreen:

        AnchorLayout:

            anchor_y: "top"
            anchor_x: "center"

            Button:

                text: root.button_text
                size:(200,50)
                size_hint:(None,None)
                on_release: root.open_drop_down(self)

<CustomDropDown2>:

    Button:
        text:"Item 1"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("ONE")
    Button:
        text:"Item 2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("TWO")
    Button:
        text:"Item 3"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("THREE")



<CustomDropDown1>:

    CustomDropDown2:
    CustomDropDown2:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'debug.py' file, add a CustomDropDown class and an 'open_drop_down()' method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    button_text = StringProperty('Show possibilities')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown(self)

    def open_drop_down(self, widget):            
        self.dropdown.open(widget)

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager

    def on_select(self, data):
        self.sm.button_text = data

Builder.load_file("debug.kv")

class MyAppli(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

Then modify your 'debug.kv' file to use the CustomDropDown:

```
<MyScreenManager>:

    MyScreen:

        BoxLayout:

            Button:

                text: root.button_text
                size:(200,50)
                size_hint:(None,None)
                on_release: root.open_drop_down(self)

<CustomDropDown>:
    Button:
        text:"Item 1"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("ONE")
    Button:
        text:"Item 2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text:"Item 3"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("THREE")
```

The DropDown menu will attach to the widget passed to the `open()` method, so in this case it attach to the "Show Possibilities" button".

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it works. However when I select for example the 'Item 2' button, the main button does not change its text, it still display "Show possibilities". Do you know how to fix that ? Last thing, when I click, the dropdown is unrolled up, but I want it down. Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: I can now dropdown towards bottom, I just changed the button's position.

Comment: In your `MyScreenManager` class create a StringProperty:
 `button_text = StringProperty('Show possibilities')` and reference it in your kv file: `text: root.button_text`. Then to change it just do `button_text = "something different"`.

Comment: I'm trying but I can't do that.. Could you please edit your code ? Thank you.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'MyScreenManager' object has no attribute 'button_text'`

Comment: Edited the original answer to show how the main button text can be changed.

Comment: `self.button_text = ...` Do you know how to select by ID or any way you want, the text of the active button ? Thanks.

Comment: Edited original answer to include some code in the CustomDropDown class so that when a button is selected the main button text changes. The kv file has been changed so that the "Item 2" button passes its own text to the select method.

Comment: Do you know how to create recursive dropdown ? I mean... a dropdown that contains 3 dropdowns that contains 3 buttons each ? thanks.

Comment: You can add additional classes (like `CustomDropDown2` and `CustomDropDown3`) in your debug.py script. And also add corresponding blocks in your debug.kv file. Each dropdown class will need to create its cascading dropdown like: `self.dropdown2 = CustomDropDown2(self.sm)` where self.sm is the screen manager. Button callbacks then just open the next drop down as before. You would have to use different callbacks for each button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that but I have an error and it does not work, I don't know if I am doing that well. Could you check for my topic (I edited all the first message) please ? Thank you :)